# Angular build causing error type_check_block

Tags: angular-cli

After ng build i get:

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: Error: Could not resolve [object Object] / undefined
    at Scope.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1318:23)
    at Scope.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1315:36)
    at Scope.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1315:36)
    at Scope.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1315:36)
    at Scope.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1315:36)
    at TcbExpressionTranslator.resolveTarget (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1877:35)
    at TcbExpressionTranslator.resolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1786:29)
    at AstTranslator.maybeResolve (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1771:84)
    at AstTranslator.translate (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:74:33)
    at Object.astToTypescript (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:55:27)
    at TcbExpressionTranslator.translate (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1771:33)
    at tcbExpression (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1759:27)
    at TcbUnclaimedInputsOp.execute (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:848:32)
    at Scope.executeOp (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1428:26)
    at Scope.render (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1335:22)
    at TcbTemplateBodyOp.execute (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:318:40)
```

Dependencies I have:
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.1",
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^11.0.0",
"@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.1",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
"@types/node": "^14.14.7",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
"karma": "~5.2.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~9.0.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.5"

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw someone having that issue because he accidentally removed a module from the app's imports array. After checking my latest commits I noticed I removed the `FormsModule` from the `app.module.ts` `imports`. After re-adding, the error was gone and I could compile again without issues.